# Eslint multiple configuration comments

Tags: node.js, eslint

All,

I'm using this configuration comment at the top of my test files.

```
/* eslint-env mocha */
```

I would like to also include this comment.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
```

But I can't seem to get both of them to work together. I've tried the following.

```
// A
/* eslint-env mocha, eslint-disable no-console */

// B
/*
  eslint-env mocha
  eslint-disable no-console
*/

// C
/* eslint env: mocha, disable: no-console */
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work like this.

```
/* eslint no-console: off */
/* eslint-env mocha */
```